# php include path windows 7 wampserver

Tags: php, windows-7-x64

I have a php environment on a windows 7 machine. I would like to add php include path.  I run all my php apps from the following folder:

> c:\wamp\www(followed by the folder of the of the app I am developing)

Please Assist, I am new to php and still have a lot to learn.

> if(!defined('PHPWORD_BASE_PATH')) {
>       define('PHPWORD_BASE_PATH', dirname(**FILE**) . '/');
>       require PHPWORD_BASE_PATH . 'PHPWord/Autoloader.php';
>       PHPWord_Autoloader::Register();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your include file is in same folder you need to write as

```
<? include "file.php"; ?>
```

if it is inner folder  you need to use

```
<? include "foldername/file.php"; ?>
```

if it is in one up folder you need to use

```
<? include "../file.php"; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

if your include is in the same folder..

`<? include "file.php"; ?>`

Comment: thanks, that gave me a better understanding of the problem. I was trying to make sense of the following statement: If your PHPWord working directory isn't your PHP include path you can set the PHPWord base path. To set the PHPWord base path open the PHPWord.php inside the root folder and edit the value of PHPWORD_BASE_PATH constant.

Comment: That sounds like an option where you can set a base path and it will treat all others as if it were in that directory so you don't have to type out the full path. see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787661/define-my-own-base-path-vs-set-include-path

Comment: Thanks a lot Adelphia, I am getting smarter now

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your script is `c:\wamp\www\myscript\index.php` and your other file is `c:\wamp\www\myscript\something_else.php`.

Then you can use any of the following:

```
<? include("c:\wamp\www\myscript\something_else.php"); ?>
<? include("something_else.php"); ?>
```

The last one works if both files are in the same folder.